# Focus an input inside a custom Angular MatFormFieldControl

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

How do I make my parent component focus on the `asset1` input field inside my custom `MatFormFieldControl` on page load*?

Parent component HTML:

```
    <mat-form-field class="symbol">
      <symbol-input
        name="symbol"
        placeholder="Symbol"
        ngModel
        #symbolInput="ngModel"
        [(ngModel)]="symbol"></symbol-input>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Custom `MatFormFieldControl` HTML:

```
<div [formGroup]="parts">
  <input class="asset1" formControlName="asset1" size="12">
  <span class="input-spacer">&frasl;</span>
  <input class="asset2" formControlName="asset2" size="12">
</div>
```

*I assume i'll implement `AfterViewInit` in parent component and hopefully trigger a `focus` event that will trickle down ?

Comment: Did you implement `ControlValueAccessor` on the `SymbolInputComponent`?

Comment: @SiddAjmera yes, also, clicking the symbol-input field does focus correctly, i just want to perform this on load.

Comment: You might want to share your implementation of the `SymbolInputComponent` Class.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my implementation i just would like to know how to setup a focus when the parent field AfterViewInit runs

Comment: have you tried just setting the `autofocus` attribute on the input field? I tried on my angular app and it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@IvanS95 pointed me in the right direction.

Added a `ViewChild` to my parent component:

```
@ViewChild(SymbolInputComponent) set focus(sic: SymbolInputComponent) {
    sic.autofocus = true;
};
```

I then in my custom `MatFormFieldControl` added a public variable `autofocus` set to false. In case I need to use this field multiple times on a given page.

Then I added `autofocus` to my `MatFormFieldControl` template:

```
<div [formGroup]="parts">
  <input class="asset1" formControlName="asset1" size="12" [autofocus]="autofocus">
  <span class="input-spacer">&frasl;</span>
  <input class="asset2" formControlName="asset2" size="12">
</div>
```